# react-scripts 5 failing to bundle sub-depdendency correctly

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have a react component library that worked with react scripts 4. The library is dependent on @headlessui/react, so that is in my node_modules, but not required directly by the application, only by the component library.

I'm running into this problem: [react-script 4 to 5 migration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74456874/react-script-4-to-5-migration-issue)

When I take a close look at the output bundle in a boilerplate react-scripts 5 application, I see this in the minified source where it's supposed to require @headlessui/react:

```
      64237: function (e, t, r) {
        "use strict";
        e.exports = r.p + "static/media/index.439e41c35f66883d8abc.cjs"; <- hmmmm???
      },
```

And I can see in the build folder there's indeed a media folder with that file in it that is the headless ui code, but it's not putting the code inside the bundle

Now, I've figured out that if I remove these lines from the package.json of @headlessui/react, react-scripts 5 will bundle everything successfully:

```
  // need to remove all of these
  "exports": {
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "require": "./dist/index.cjs",
    "import": "./dist/headlessui.esm.js"
  },
```

Which makes me thing I might be able to get around it by changing webpack's config somehow using craco, but I'm not exactly sure how

Is there a webpack configuration I can provide to get webpack to ignore the exports portion of the package.json?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an unsupported feature in create-react-app

cjs files were loaded via webpack as static assets instead of code

The bug and a workaround fix is outlined in the github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11889